# Remove Filter Option from SmartTable

Tags: sapui5

We have implemented a SmartTable and everything is working fine. I would like to remove only the Filter option provided by SmartTable useTablePersonalisation option.

Is this Possible ?

Regards,
Mayank

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can remove the filter (and all other options) from the SmartTable's embedded P13nDialog via `customData` as shown in this [SAPUI5 Explored Sample: P13nDialog with disabled 'Filter' tab - Variation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.comp.sample.personalization.example7/preview).

**SmartTableWithoutFilterOption.view.xml**

```
<core:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns="sap.ui.comp.smarttable"
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:customData="http://schemas.sap.com/sapui5/extension/sap.ui.core.CustomData/1"
    controllerName="my.namespace.SmartTableWithoutFilterOption">

    <SmartTable
        tableType="ResponsiveTable" header="A bunch of data"
        enableAutoBinding="true" entitySet="RecordSet"
        customData:p13nDialogSettings='{filter:{visible:false}}' />
</core:View>
```

Please note that you need to declare the `xmlns:customData` namespace for the `customData:p13nDialogSettings` property to work.

But you can also use the longer `customData` aggregation notation.

**SmartTableWithoutFilterOptionLongNotation.view.xml**

```
<core:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns="sap.ui.comp.smarttable"
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    controllerName="my.namespace.SmartTableWithoutFilterOptionLongNotation">

    <SmartTable
        tableType="ResponsiveTable" header="A bunch of data"
        enableAutoBinding="true" entitySet="RecordSet">
        <customData>
            <core:CustomData
                key="p13nDialogSettings"
                value='\{
                    "filter": \{ "visible": false}
                }' />
        </customData>
    </SmartTable>
</core:View>
```

To hide the other options use `columns`, `sort` or `group` instead of `filter`.
You can also combine these settings to hide more than one option. The following code will only allow filtering.

```
<core:CustomData
    key="p13nDialogSettings"
    value='\{
        "columns": \{ "visible": false},
        "sort": \{ "visible": false},
        "group": \{ "visible": false}
    }' />
```